# How to check the current disk space used by my linux?

Tags: linux, unix

The entire box. How many gigs is everything using?

And how do I check total?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At a command line, type

```
df -a
```

This will list each device and usage information.

You might find

```
df -h
```

more readable, since it gives quantities in Gb or Mb, etc.

Answer (score 10):

As suggested by others, `du` and `df` can easily do the job, but [baobab](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/index.html) (see screenshot below) is a great tool for analysing disk usage of whole file system or specific folders.

If you are using ubuntu, then baobab is already installed. Start it from `Menu->Accessories->Disk Usage Analyzer` or type `baobab` in a terminal window.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
du . -h --max-depth=1
```

lists the size of all the folders in the current directory (or at a location of your choice)

Answer (score 3):

Here are some approaches:

```
df -h
```

Or install the totally awesome ***[kdirstat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/)*** graphical utility:

[image]

Comment: Is this based on WinDirStat, or is it the other way around?

Comment: Actually, `kDirStat` came first, something the kDirStat folks are rather sensitive about. (Apparently most people just assume the win version same first. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
df -h
```

Answer (score 1):

```
du -sh folder
```

tells you how much folder is taking space. You can list multiple directories at once or use *.

```
df -h
```

tells you the total space of each mount point.

You can omit h (human readable) from both if you want to know the exact amounts.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu):

> Not quite happy with the available disk usage analyzers and looking
>   for a fun project to get used to C programming, I started working on
>   ncdu: A disk usage analyzer with an ncurses interface, aimed to be run
>   on a remote server where you don't have an entire gaphical setup, but
>   have to do with a simple SSH connection. ncdu aims to be fast, simple
>   and easy to use, and should be able to run in any minimal POSIX-like
>   environment with ncurses installed.

Answer (score 0):

[du](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/du/)

Comment: `du` by itself gives disk usage for the current directory