# Windows 10 VirtualBox - Ubuntu 14.04.4 disk space capped at 1GB

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtualbox, memory

I have a Windows 10 machine, with VirtualBox v5.0.16 r105871 installed. Over this, I am trying to host an Ubuntu 14.04.4 OS so that I can install and run the Robot Operating System (ROS). Here are some screenshots that show my setup:

The initial install of ROS desktop needs about 1.5GB, so I allocated 4GB of space for the Ubuntu OS. During installation, I run out of memory. This is the screenshot from Terminal:

[image: ROS installation failed]
<sup>click to enlarge</sup>

So I go into the System Monitor to check. But everything looks fine - I have 4 GB and 3GB more to go:

[image: System Monitor (only 1 GB used)]
<sup>click to enlarge</sup>

I followed the installation instructions at the ROS Indigo installation site to reach this point, and I'm stuck. I highly suspect that has nothing to do with ROS and can be solved if I can get the Ubuntu OS to recognize all 4GB of the disk, but I don't seem to be fiddling with the right controls.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: As @Deltik mentions below, I think you're confusing memory/RAM with disk space here.  To check for free space on Ubuntu, see this possible duplicate: [How to determine available free space on Ubuntu?](http://superuser.com/questions/94563/how-to-determine-available-free-space-on-ubuntu)  (also, FWIW, 4GB is pretty small - I'd recommend choosing a much larger size like 40GB, but in a dynamically expanding volume, so it only takes up as much disk space is as written by the VM and not the entire 40GB).

Answer (score 0):

I think you've confused *disk space* and *memory*.  You ran out of *disk space*, which you strongly suggested in your first screenshot.  You did not run out of *memory*, as shown in your second screenshot.

`df -hT` will report your filesystem disk space usage. You can figure out which filesystem filled up (most likely `/`).

You can visualize what is taking up so much disk space with `baobab` (GNOME Disk Usage Analyzer), which may be built into Ubuntu 14.04 already.

If you can't delete anything else, you should have installed Ubuntu on a larger disk or partitioned the disk more effectively.  There are ways to resize existing installations, but that's a much broader topic than in the scope of this answer.